# How can check if a button was clicked a second time?

Tags: html, angular

I have a button in html that i want to make a search bar appear when clicked and make it disappear when clicked a second time. I already know how to do the first one but i don't know how to to do the second one.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are asking for a toggle switch, on/off or true/false state. Simply declare a local variable in your component and set it false initially. Change it once the button is clicked -

```html
    <button (click)="onClick()">
    <div *ngIf="showSearchbar">this is searchbar</div>
```

```js
    showSearchbar: boolean;

    onClick() {
      this.showSearchbar = !this.showSearchbar;
    }
```